# How do I attach a prawnto-rendered .pdf to an email in Rails 2.3.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, pdf, attachment

My application creates a .pdf file when it is rendered by passing it to the URL (for example, domain.com/letter/2.pdf)

**It doesn't get saved anywhere.**

How can I make that actual pdf an attachment in an outbound email.

Here is my mailer:

```
  def campaign_email(contact,email)
    subject    email.subject
    recipients contact.email
    from       'Me <me@me.com>'
    sent_on    Date.today

    attachment = File.read("http://localhost:3000/contact_letters/#{attachment.id}.pdf")

   attachment "application/pdf" do |a|
    a.body = attachment
    a.filename = "Othersheet.pdf" 
   end
 end
```

This is the controller that creates/renders the PDF:

```
def create
    @contact_letter = ContactLetter.new(params[:contact_letter])

    @contact = Contact.find_by_id(@contact_letter.contact_id)
    @letter = Letter.find_by_id(@contact_letter.letter_id)

    if @contact_letter.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created contact letter."

      #redirect_to contact_path(@contact_letter.contact_id)
      redirect_to contact_letter_path(@contact_letter, :format => 'pdf')
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

NOTE:  I hardcoded localhost:3000/ how can I substitute that with a variable so that on dev it is localhost:3000 and on production is it the correct domain?  Is there a way to include routing in this?)

ERROR:  I get an

> Invalid argument -
>   http://localhost:3000/contact_letters/9.pdf

Comment: are you on rails 2 or 3?

Comment: can you also show the code from the letter-controller that sends the pdf?

Comment: yeah, I can show the controller, editing above.

Comment: what are you using to create the PDF file? PDFKit? Perhaps showing the code that generates the file would help.

Comment: I am using Prawn to generate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by passing the pdf object directly into the campaign_email method and then assigning an attachment.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example for rails 2

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
# attachments
def signup_notification(recipient, letter)
  recipients      recipient.email_address_with_name
  subject         "New account information"
  from            "system@example.com"

  attachment :content_type => "image/jpeg",
    :body => File.read("an-image.jpg")

  attachment "application/pdf" do |a|
    a.body = letter
  end
end
end
```

in your view or wherever your calling your method:

```
ApplicationMailer.deliver_signup_notification(letter)
```

Comment: that, or the method your using to create your pdf

Comment: This is the path in the create method:  contact_letter_path(@contact_letter, :format => 'pdf') is that what I put there?

Comment: contact_letter_path puts out what you want, so: letter = contact_letter_path(@contact_letter, :format => 'pdf')

Comment: then pass letter to ActionMailer: I made edits to my response

Comment: you mean, letter as an object?

Comment: So before I use signup_notificaiton, I use letter = contact_letter_path(@contact_letter, :format => 'pdf" -- that will store in the letter object the pdf which can then be attached?

Comment: why does the deliver_signup_notification(letter) only pass letter, but not pass recipient, although signup_notification needs two params?

Comment: This doesn't appear to work...it looks like there needs to be an open file command necessary...

Answer (score 0):

one quick an easy solution would be fetch the url content using net/http and open-uri, to get the attachment

```
attachments['free_book.pdf'] = open("http://#{request.host}/letter/#{id}.pdf")
```

eg:

```
def campaign_email(contact,email)
    subject    email.subject
    recipients contact.email
    attachments['free_book.pdf'] = open("http://#{request.host}/letter/#{id}.pdf")
    from       'Me <me@me.com>'
    sent_on    Date.today

    body       :email => email
end
```

or, call the PDF generation inside your mailer controller action

Comment: how do I call the PDF generate inside the mailer controller action?  could I use

Comment: attachments['free.pdf'] = open(contact_letter_path(@contact_letter, :format => 'pdf'))